# Linking to Kernel32.lib in assembler

Tags: winapi, assembly, nasm

I started learning assembly today and have ran many tests on linux that worked very well! I moved over to my PC and started to attempt to write some here. I ran into a problem when attempting to call external functions (which again, worked fine on linux) where I would get LINK 2001 Unresolved External errors telling me that WriteConsoleA is not defined when after compiling with nasm:

```
nasm -f win32 test.asm -o test.obj
```

and with cl.exe:

```
cl test.obj /link libcmt.lib kernel32.lib
```

I get these errors:

```
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ExitProcess
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol GetStdHandle
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol WriteConsoleA
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

The assembly:

```
extern ExitProcess, GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA
NULL equ 0
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11
section .data
   msg db "Hello world!",0xa
msgLen equ $-msg
section .bss
    dummy resd 1
section .text
    global _main
_main:
    push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    push NULL
    push dummy
    push msgLen
    push msg
    push eax
    call WriteConsoleA
    push NULL
    call ExitProcess
```

Copied almost exactly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574924/hello-world-using-nasm-in-windows-assembly).
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, cl is not a linker but a compiler.  Why not just use GoLink as I shown in the post you linked to?  It is much easier to use.  You could use ld as the linker, but your externs will change a bit.

Windows API functions use function name decorations - an underscore + FunctionName + @sizeof parameters, this is a linker thing.

So, ExitProcess is really exported as _ExitProcess@4 since it takes 1 DWORD parameter.  WriteConsoleA takes 5 parameters DWORD sized, so it would be _WriteConsole@20

Change your code to:

```
extern _ExitProcess@4, _GetStdHandle@4, _WriteConsoleA@20

%define ExitProcess _ExitProcess@4
%define GetStdHandle _GetStdHandle@4
%define WriteConsoleA _WriteConsoleA@20

NULL equ 0
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11
section .data
   msg db "Hello world!",0xa   
msgLen equ $-msg

section .bss
    dummy resd 1

section .text
    global _main
_main:
    push STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle

    push NULL
    push dummy
    push msgLen
    push msg
    push eax
    call WriteConsoleA

    push NULL
    call ExitProcess
```

To link with ld, tell it where the lib directory is, a good bet is:
-L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Lib"

then just use the `-l` flag with the library 
-l kernel32

My makefile using NASM and ld for your sample code:

```
APP= Sample

all: $(APP) clean

$(APP): $(APP).obj
    "C:\MinGW\bin\ld" $(APP).obj -o $(APP).exe -L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Lib" -l kernel32

$(APP).obj: $(APP).asm
    nasm -f win32 $(APP).asm -o $(APP).obj

clean:
    rm $(APP).obj
```

If you were to use GoLink as in the other post, you could just use the API Function names as they appear in the docs.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more quick question, how come when I run it on linux I create the executable with the .o using gcc?

Comment: Windows use .obj files, Linux uses .o files.

Comment: I was told there was no difference. (Well no different in the same way .dlls and .so's are similar but different at the same time)

Comment: an `o` file (object file) on Linux is much different than an `obj` file in Windows, they are not interchangeable.

Comment: I understand that they're not interchangeable but what does each one contain?

Comment: A little research on your part will make you a better programmer.

Comment: Yeah. Just did that. :P
I usually google for many hours before posting here. (Which I did do before this question as well)