# why the @number symbol at the end of an exported dll function

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport, dumpbin

I have a dll that contains more then 400 function, and my exe file is using only 15 function from the dll, so i need to create a new dll and export the functions and fake their return values to simulate an output of a more complex system.

What i have tried :

```
 #include "stdafx.h"

//the compiler complains about the '@20'

__declspec ( dllexport ) XLStatus _xlActivateChannel@20(XLportHandle,  XLuint64, unsigned int, unsigned int)
{
    return 0;
} 

// causing the exe to crash
```

dumpbin /exports vxlapi.dll (original dll): show duplicate function names  (not for all functions)

```
ordinal  name
         _xlActivateChannel@20
14       xlActivateChannel
```

Note : in the header file of the dll, the functions are declared like so:

```
DECL_STDXL_FUNC ( xlActivateChannel, XLACTIVATECHANNEL, (
                  XLportHandle  portHandle,
                  XLaccess      accessMask,
                  unsigned int  busType,
                  unsigned int  flags)
                  );
```

in dumpbin / export dll 
why there are function names starting with an '_' underscore and ending with '@number' , Note: the exe is using the let's say(decorated) functions, and how can i create a new dll and export functions that contains @,

Comment: First, the "@" denotes the number of bytes the parameter list takes up.  Second, to get rid of the "@", [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282683/dll-call-with-stdcall-getprocaddress-in-vs2013/31283377#31283377).  In short, you need to use a module definition file in your build of the DLL.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie its mentionned that a .def file is not needed when using __declspec(dllexport) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?view=vs-2017#remarks

Comment: Of course you don't need a DEF file.  You *do* need one if you expect to have your exported function names to use no decoration whatsoever (just a clean function name without any decoration).  I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but whatever it is, you need to know when, where, and why all of those decorations are done -- isn't that the question you were asking?  There is the `C++` name mangling, and the Windows "mangling" -- both are separate, and both handled differently.

Comment: by a module definition file you mean a header file isn't it ? excuse me im new to this, and c++

Comment: No, a module definition file is merely a text file that describes your exports, and optionally gives them a "clean" name.  That's the only way I know of to accomplish creating exported names using the Visual C++ toolset, and have the exported names show up without any *Windows* decoration (the "@" stuff).  This has been the case since I believe the Windows OS was created, even back in the 16-bit days, and it has not changed since.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what i want to accomplish is to redefine the 15 functions in a new dll and substitute the old dll

Comment: I don't think you're going about this the right way.  The "old" DLL remains as is.  Your DLL simply calls the old DLL functions in a new exported function that you defined.  Maybe you're overcomplicating this whole thing.  All of this stuff with renaming functions, figuring out exports, etc.  I don't think any of that is necessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you mean dll injection , and then export the newly created functions with the same name using a .def file ? actually i have tried that and it works but the responsible didn't like that.. I'm confused, here is my email: belha99@hotmail.fr I'd need some help(orientation) in this If you mind

Comment: No, not DLL injection.  You create a "regular" DLL that simply has function(s) that call the original DLL's functions.  Can you do that?  If so, then just wrap those function you created that calls/wraps the original functions and export those new function.

Comment: Now its clear to me , I will try that, Thanks a lot!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["@n" is used by the `stdcall`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039697/what-is-the-n-at-sign-after-every-function-name) calling convention.  You don't need to mention it in your declaration, you just need to change your declaration to `stdcall` so that the compiler knows they need to be decorated with "@n" suffixes.  Like this:

```
__declspec ( dllexport ) XLStatus __stdcall _xlActivateChannel(XLportHandle,  XLuint64, unsigned int, unsigned int)
```

Comment: I think the **__stdcall** should be placed right before the function name

Comment: @Stoura: Thanks, you're right, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Name mangling is typical for C++ etc which is why you see these symbols in the exports. Ansi C exports are not mangled.  The @ symbol is not allowed.  You might try AT or _AT.

extern "C" is used to remove mangling for C types. Is does not work with class or other C++ types.

I read too fast, but John is more correct.

Comment: Typical C compilers **do** mangle names, by prepending an underscore.