# GCC How declare and link extern Kernel32.LIB functions with '@'

Tags: winapi, gcc, compilation, g++, undefined-reference

Kernel.LIB file content

> _ExitProcess@4, _GetStdHandle@4, _WriteConsoleA@20

1. For use this, I've tested to declare :

   ```
       void WINAPI ExitProcess(unsigned int ExitCode);
       HANDLE WINAPI GetStdHandle(DWORD nStdHandle);
       bool WINAPI WriteConsole@20(HANDLE hConsoleOutput, const void *lpBuffer DWOR......)
   ```

   But this not work. (undefined reference).
2. I've tested with "@n"

   ```
   void WINAPI ExitProcess@4(unsigned int ExitCode);
   HANDLE WINAPI GetStdHandle@4(DWORD nStdHandle);
   bool WINAPI WriteConsole@20(HANDLE hConsoleOutput, const void *lpBuffer DWOR......)
   ```

   But this syntax is not allowed.

I've found [Linking to Kernel32.lib in assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063224/linking-to-kernel32-lib-in-assembler/38552129#38552129)

**This solution is good, but only for nasm so, my question is :**

How do use this in **C/C++** with **G++/GCC** ?

```
extern _ExitProcess@4, _GetStdHandle@4, _WriteConsoleA@20

%define ExitProcess _ExitProcess@4
%define GetStdHandle _GetStdHandle@4
%define WriteConsoleA _WriteConsoleA@20
```

Because " **@4 @20** " was not allowed syntax in C/C++

Comment: You have to include `windows.h`. Then the undecorated functions are automatically available.

Comment: Thank you, but when i compile, my compiler can't link symbol
example:
"undefined reference ExitProcess" and when I edit my OBJ file with CFF explorer, I've "ExitProcess" and no "_ExitProcess@4"

Another example, if I compile with "ExitProcessXX" symbol name, and with CCF explorer I edit this "XX" by "@4" in my OBJ file, the compiler can compile...

So.. How to include this "@n" during compilation ?

Regards