# Why am I getting an error message from this nasm?

Tags: assembly, windows-7, nasm

I'm getting an error while executing this on windows 7 32 bits:

```
SECTION .data       ; data section
msg:    db "Hello World",10 ; the string to print, 10=cr
len:    equ $-msg       ; "$" means "here"
            ; len is a value, not an address

SECTION .text       ; code section
    global main     ; make label available to linker 
main:               ; standard  gcc  entry point

mov edx,len     ; arg3, length of string to print
mov ecx,msg     ; arg2, pointer to string
mov ebx,1       ; arg1, where to write, screen
mov eax,4       ; write sysout command to int 80 hex
int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel

mov ebx,0       ; exit code, 0=normal
mov eax,1       ; exit command to kernel
int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel
```

The program exits with no output. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What error message? You forgot to mention, but say "no output".

Comment: @WeatherVane It only show a window and exit with no message of error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hello world using nasm in windows assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574924/hello-world-using-nasm-in-windows-assembly)  . You can get the `golink` linker in the answer from [here](http://www.godevtool.com/GolinkFrame.htm)